# NiFi: Route on Remote Process Group Availability?

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there a preferred way to route a FlowFile based on a downstream condition?

Specifically, I have a processing chain that sends FlowFiles to a Remote Process Group (RPG) ... but if the RPG is not available, then I'd like to route to a different, local processing chain.

A hacky solution might involve a Wait processor (e.g., route "Expired" FlowFiles to the "RPG Unavailable" processing chain), but I can readily come up with a variety of problems with that approach ...

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't want the data to queue up before the RPG and wait til the downstream NiFi instance/cluster is available again? I'm not sure how you would know the entire destination cluster is unavailable ahead of time.

Comment: @BryanBende Its a very specific use-case, but I'm trying to build a topology that can be used for a number of weeks while waiting for accreditation of a network connection.  Then, when the network connection is accredited / turned on, the RPG becomes available.  Is there a way to modify a PG variable from a processor within the group?  If so, i could ping the RPG connection and update a "rpgAvailable" variable (and then use that with RouteOnAttribute) ...

Comment: You could do this with an `ExecuteScript` processor hitting the REST API of the NiFi instance. I agree it's a unique case and there isn't something native to do this well. You could also have two distinct flows: one that puts the data into a buffer or temporary storage, and another triggered by a ping command result or boolean flag that pulls the data from the temp storage and sends it to the RPG.

Comment: Yea similar to what Andy said, I was going to say two separate parts of the flow, one that checks the status and puts the result in the distributed map cache, and then the other part fetches the results from the cache and makes a decision where to go

Comment: The RPG could be executed in the same machine, so you can create the complete flow with the RPG and required inputs, and when you have the connection you are waiting for, only need to change the RPG url.